# barCodeTypes not work in react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I use react-native-camera as barcode scanner. Then I want it scan all 1D barcode not QRCode.
I use barCodeTypes to declare which barcode type search for:

```js
onBarCodeRead={(e) => this.onScanSuccess(e)}
barcodeTypes={[RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.ean13,RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.ean8]}>
```

But it still detect QRCode in image has both EAN_13 and QRCode.

Anyone can give a suggestion about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: experience the same problem..